# gh-pages script cannot commit .nojekyll to GitHub

Tags: reactjs, git, next.js, github-pages

I have the following script in my `package.json` for my `NextJS` project.

```
"predeploy": "next build && next export && cp CNAME out/CNAME && cp .nojekyll out/.nojekyll",
"deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d out",
```

Both `CNAME` and `.nojekyll` are being copied to `out` folder successfully but for unknown reason, unlike `CNAME`, `.nojekyll` is not being included in the commit. What is the possible reason? Is it because of the dot (`.`)?

Answer (score 4):

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d out -t true"
```

should do the trick